# Chef workflow for new cookbooks

Tags: workflow, chef-infra, chef-solo

While building my own cookbooks I find myself constantly within this cycle:

1. Change cookbook on my local computer
2. Upload modified cookbook to chef server
3. Run chef-client on remote machine
4. Repeat

Since I am new to chef, I repeat that cycle **extremely** often, but I find rather cumbersome uploading and downloading so frequently from the chef server.

How experienced chef users ease this cycle? I learnt Chef with the free hosted solution, but I am not sure if I should be better off using just Chef-solo and move back later to the hosted version once I have many servers and more experience with chef.

Is there maybe a workflow where I can quickly try changes to my cookbooks directly on my remote machine while using hosted Chef but without uploading them?

Comment: Have you looked at Berkshelf + TK + Vagrant?

Comment: I heard about that combo, but I thought it was a more advanced topic related only with testing. I just have one small server and two workstations used only by me and registered as nodes of the free hosted chef. At the moment I just want to gain experience, get familiar with chef and run quickly my modifications without a loop involving a slow roundtrip of many machines. I even had to replace Berkshelf for librarian because it was forcing me a complex workflow more appropriate for a server farm with multiple devops

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do all my development locally on my laptop, using [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/). When the cookbook is ready, it gets pushed to it's new Git repository home and integrated into my production chef server infrastructure.

The following example runs nginx on a virtualbox image.

## Example

Install vagrant plugins (only needs to be done once):

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-omnibus
vagrant plugin install vagrant-berkshelf
vagrant plugin install vagrant-chef-zero
```

Use [Berkshelf](http://berkshelf.com/) to generate a new [application cookbook](http://red-badger.com/blog/2013/06/24/berkshelf-application-cookbooks/).

```
$ berks cookbook demo
      create  demo/files/default
      create  demo/templates/default
      create  demo/attributes
      create  demo/definitions
      create  demo/libraries
      create  demo/providers
      create  demo/recipes
      create  demo/resources
      create  demo/recipes/default.rb
      create  demo/metadata.rb
      create  demo/LICENSE
      create  demo/README.md
      create  demo/Berksfile
      create  demo/Thorfile
      create  demo/chefignore
      create  demo/.gitignore
         run  git init from "./demo"
      create  demo/Gemfile
      create  demo/Vagrantfile
```

Edit the following files (Details below):

1. Vagrantfile         <-- Controls vagrant's operation
2. metadata.rb         <-- List community cookbook dependencies
3. recipes/default.rb  <-- Calls to community cookbook recipes and LWRPs

Running vagrant will startup a virtual machine that is provisioned using chef-client. The [chef zero](https://github.com/opscode/chef-zero) plugin will run a local embedded instance of chef-server. The berkself plugin is used to automatically load the cookbook dependencies.

```
vagrant up
```

The following command will rerun chef-client (following edits):

```
vagrant provision
```

Finally, the really big advantage of doing development, using local virtualization, is that you can tear everything down and build it again from scratch:

```
vagrant destroy -f && vagrant up
```

### Vagrantfile

Controls vagrant's operation. In this case I'm only starting a single VM, provisioned using chef-client:

```
Vagrant.require_plugin "vagrant-omnibus"
Vagrant.require_plugin "vagrant-berkshelf"
Vagrant.require_plugin "vagrant-chef-zero"

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  # Box config
  config.vm.box = "saucy64"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/saucy/current/saucy-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box"

  # Virtualbox config
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 1024]
  end

  # Networking config
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.0.10"

  # Plugin config
  config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest
  config.chef_zero.enabled = true
  config.berkshelf.enabled = true

  # Chef config
  config.vm.provision :chef_client do |chef|
    chef.add_recipe "demo"
  end
end
```

The omnibus plugin is responsible for installing the desired version of chef. The Berkshelf plugin will download cookbook dependencies and when combined with chef-zero will upload cookbooks during each provision run.

### metadata.rb

Add nginx as a cookbook dependency:

```
name             'demo'
maintainer       'YOUR_NAME'
maintainer_email 'YOUR_EMAIL'
license          'All rights reserved'
description      'Installs/Configures demo'
long_description IO.read(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'README.md'))
version          '0.1.0'

depends "nginx"
```

The *Berksfile* is preconfigured to load the cookbook dependencies, listed in the metadata file, from the community cookbook repository.

```
site :opscode

metadata
```

### recipes/default.rb

Run the default nginx recipe

```
#
# Cookbook Name:: demo
# Recipe:: default
#
# Copyright (C) 2014 YOUR_NAME
# 
# All rights reserved - Do Not Redistribute
#

include_recipe "nginx"
```

Answer (score 1):

I go through that loop most of the time during my testings. But I also use Chef solo when I need to try several minor changes in a recipe. If you have a test machine with a local copy of  your chef repo then you can try making changes there and running chef solo to see the results. This way there's no uploading.