# How to include Chef community cookbookes?

Tags: git, chef-infra

I am a chef beginner trying to use some community cookbooks you can find on the [Chef community page](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/).

From some programming experience I feel that simply downloading the cookbooks and put them in my repository is not a good idea. Every time I would like to update the community cookbooks I would have to download them and do it all over again. I would like to have a simple way to update the cookbooks.

Is git submodules a way to go? Or is there some "cookbooks manager"? How do you include the community cookbooks?

Comment: We are using Berkshelf for what you are describing. http://berkshelf.com/

Comment: Related link on using Berkshelf to manage cookbooks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531452/chef-workflow-for-new-cookbooks/22546531#22546531

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The officially recommended pathway is [Berkshelf](http://berkshelf.com).

There are other tools, such as Librarian and `knife coookbook site install` that can perform the same operations.

Comment: Thanks. In case I don't need ruby installed on my server, I guess it's okay to install the cookbooks to my folder using `berks --path` and then version them using git, right?